# Allow a vi node to accept any input type

Tags: templates, labview, variant

I want to create a VI that will accept an Integer,float,bool,string, or enum as an input node (but only a single node), then inside my VI detect the input type so that I can use the data in different ways. Can anyone point me in the right direction with this, I'm thinking about variants but not really sure how to go about it.

I want my VI to basically work in the same way that a C++ function using a template type, or an overloaded function would work.

Thanks,
Eamonn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some additional options:

1. There should be some shipping VIs which tell you what the type of the data in the variant is. This should simplify the previous suggestion, because you simply start with a case structure and cast to one type inside each case. The VIs should be in vi.lib, I believe in a folder called VariantDataType or possibly in the Utility folder.
2. Create a polymorphic VI - it's basically a group of VIs (one for each data type) which are connected using the poly VI. Once you drop it in the diagram, LV automatically selects the correct VI based on the the type of wire you use. The big advantage with this is that the code is simple and clear.

Comment: Specifically, <Labview>\vi.lib\Utility\VariantDataType\GetTypeInfo.vi

Answer (score 2):

You can use variants. A LabVIEW variant allows any data type as an input. To do anything useful with the variant, you will need to use "Variant to Data" and convert the variant to a usable data type.

Now, the easiest way to accomplish what you are doing is to simply to cycle through the various data types you want to use and call "Variant to Data" for all of them and check for errors. Only the proper data type will run without generating an error.

There are other ways to dynamically cast variants, but they are much more complicated (Either encoding the variant with more data or writing a parser by hand).

LabVIEW does not have very good templating or overloading features (You can use overloading but it only applies to LabVIEW Objects, most LabVIEW data types are not Objects).

Answer (score 0):

Polimorphic vi sounds like a good solution, but in this case you need to wire you data to vi so compiler know what kind of data expected before run. It does not work for the situation when you send different data types to vi at runtime. Scanning through variant will work, or you may create a cluster of string/enum with data type description and variant data, then recepient vi will know the data type. 
Yair, very interesting, this is first time I hear about checking of type of data in the variant, these vis are in vi.lib\Utility\VariantDataType but I dont see them in palettes.